# How can i read and write values from a map in firestore from react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database field which has a map like this in firestore:

cordinates:{_01:"copper",_02:"gold",_03:"iron"}

i see this database in firestore admin panel like this:
[pic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hv956ISlHVr9RfRpnBBJrV9Q1ur_Lj-M/view?usp=sharing)

when i try to list items with the code below

```
data.cordinates.map((item, i)=>
                  console.log(i+" - "+item)
                );
```

i receive:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data.cordinates.map is not a function
```

what is the correct way to read/write this kind of map?

btw console.log(data.cordinates) give me output like this:

```
{_01: "copper", _02: "gold", _03: "iron", _04: "", _05: "", …}
_01: "copper"
_02: "gold"
_03: "iron"
_04: ""
_05: ""
_06: ""
_07: ""
_08: ""
_10: ""
_11: ""
_12: ""
_13: ""
_14: ""
_15: ""
_16: ""
_17: ""
_18: ""
_20: ""
_21: ""
_22: ""
_23: ""
_24: ""
_25: ""
_26: ""
_27: ""
_28: ""
_30: ""
_31: ""
_32: ""
_33: ""
_34: ""
_35: ""
_36: ""
_37: ""
_38: ""
_40: ""
_41: ""
_42: ""
_43: ""
_44: ""
_45: ""
_46: ""
_47: ""
_48: ""
```

yes there are 48 elements in total

Any help is aprreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unclear.  What exactly is `data.cordinates` at that point in your code?  What are you expecting that code to do?  It looks like you're actually trying to just iterate the fields of that object (it's not an array).  You wouldn't normally do this with a traditional map operation.

Comment: Please paste the structure of data. i.e console.log(data);

Comment: `cordinates` is an `Object` not an `array`. `map` works on array.

Comment: @SonuBamniya so how can i retrieve an object like this?

Comment: @GangadharGandi added console.log

Comment: use `for(let i in obj){}` loop instead.

Comment: It sounds like you want to [iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties).

Comment: @DougStevenson i am trying to read some of the field properties at once as firestore billing is counted per "read" so i didnt make seperate 40 fields alone but also i need to be able to edit these fields easily so didnt make it array. (for example as far as i know i cant edit the third field alone seperately) Each user will read these fields at least once when page loaded, so i want to make the database fields as less as possible or should i switch to firebase as it doesnt count "reads"

Comment: All that data is in just one document, which only requires one read to get it all into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `map` to `forin`

Here is example code:

```
const cord = data.cordinates || {} // to handle undefined `data.cordinates` case
for(let i in cord){
   if(cord.hasOwnProperty(i)){
     const item = cord[i];
     console.log(i+" - "+item);
     // do your other stuff here
   }
}
```

Comment: i get Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): cord.hasOwnPorperty is not a function error

Comment: Ah! there is typo it should be `cord.hasOwnProperty(i)`. Updated my answer as well.

Comment: thank you, can you show me how to update one the object field propery also. let say i want to update _03:gold to _03:iron var mineupgrade =  db.collection("kullanici").doc(user);
        mineupgrade.update({
          cordinates:[...,_03:"iron"]
        }); can work?